# C-c C-c does not start a viewer

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm on a recent install of Ubuntu 18.04, with emacs 25.2.2, and auctex installed via the package manager.

When I type C-c C-c to view a recently latex'ed document, Emacs launches the command TeX-evince-sync-view.  Then nothing happens.  I see no evidence of a command being issued in the *Messages* buffer or in the TeX * path_to_my_file output * buffer.

I have tried playing around with the TeX-view-program-list variable (which by default appears to be 'nil) but I have a caveman's knowledge of lisp and don't really know what I'm doing.

Output after setting `debug-on-entry` on `TeX-evince-sync-view` is

```
Debugger entered--entering a function: * TeX-evince-sync-view() 
TeX-run-function("View" "TeX-evince-sync-view" "foo")
TeX-run-discard-or-function("View" "TeX-evince-sync-view" "foo")
TeX-command("View" TeX-master-file nil)
TeX-command-master(nil)
funcall-interactively(TeX-command-master nil)
call-interactively(TeX-command-master nil nil)
command-execute(TeX-command-master)
```

Comment: 'C-c C-v' is the quick short cut that produces no messages in other buffers.  What happens if you try to select "View" from the "Command" menu? This will at least write in the minibuffer the command that it will try to run.

Comment: I edited the title to fix a typo.  C-c C-c is the keystroke in question.  When I select 'view' from the 'command' menu the minibuffer is populated with 

"View command: TeX-evince-sync-view"

just like if I hit C-c C-c.  My issue is that this command seems to have no effect.

Comment: Have you tried debugging that function, i.e. `M-x debug-on-entry` then enter `TeX-evince-sync-view`, and thereafter try to run the command as you describe

Comment: Not the same system here however I thought across platforms CcC- compile and CcC-view were **the emacs-auctex default** so I have to V after C unless yours has been totally reconfigured which you would need to explain where

Comment: @KJO: Typing C-c C-c in auctex will do whatever the document needs next.  If it has not been compiled, it will compile.  If the .bib has changed it will BibTeX.  If everything is compiled, it will launch a viewer.  I've used these keystrokes for 25 years or so.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks for the pointer to the debugger.  It is doing something but I'm not good enough with lisp to spot the error.  When entering the function I see:
<pre> <code>
Debugger entered--entering a function:
 * TeX-evince-sync-view()
  TeX-run-function("View" "TeX-evince-sync-view" "foo")
  TeX-run-discard-or-function("View" "TeX-evince-sync-view" "foo")
  TeX-command("View" TeX-master-file nil)
  TeX-command-master(nil)
  funcall-interactively(TeX-command-master nil)
  call-interactively(TeX-command-master nil nil)
  command-execute(TeX-command-master)
</pre>

Comment: Steven it is better you edit your question with the output.  I have pasted it in this time.  However, having got to that stage, emacs is just about to enter the function in question.  You need to step through its execution with the `d` command and see what happens.  See the elisp manual's section "Debugging > Debugger > Debugger Commands"

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks.  I found the emacs debugger page and had poked around with d's and c's, but since I don't program lisp I don't know what I'm looking for.  As far as I can tell the function runs to completion.  Occasionally a return value is 'nil, but I don't know when that's intentional or not.